# Change column names of data.frame based on column number and text

Tags: r, dataframe

In the data.frame `run`

```
run <- data.frame(1:4,2:5,3:6)
  X1.4 X2.5 X3.6
1    1    2    3
2    2    3    4
3    3    4    5
4    4    5    6
```

I want to change the column names to

```
> colnames(run) <- c("runner1", "runner2", "runner3")
```

Is there a way to do this in R code (imagine I have hundreds of columns) by combining a similar text `runner` with a serial number `1, 2, 3...`

I started with
`c(rbind(rep(c("runner"), each=3), c(1:3)))` which does not work and is probably way too complicated.

I suppose there is a easy solution?

Comment: Yes, I’ll mark it as duplicate, although the question you are referring to is not entirely clear to me (but the answers point in the same direction and do answer my question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `paste0`.

```
run <- data.frame(1:4,2:5,3:6)
colnames(run) <- paste0("runner", 1:ncol(run))
```